# Messanger differences in WP8 and Win8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I have a simple questions why on these two platforms my code is working in different way.
In first step I am sending a message, using command binded to the button in UI from `MainViewModel`.

```
private RelayCommand<Set> _setCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Set> SetCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _setCommand
                ?? (_setCommand = new RelayCommand<Set>(
                    set =>
                    {
                        _navigationService.Navigate("QuestionView", set);
                        Messenger.Default.Send<Set, QuestionViewModel>(set);
                    }));
        }
    }
```

In the second step I register message in constructor in `QuestionViewModel` like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<Set>(this, Load);
```

In this solution I use PCL to sharing the code between platforms.

In the third step I would like to fire Load method, simple:

```
private void Load(Set set)
    {
        Load(set, 1);
    }
```

And in the Windows Store project everything works as I expected, but in the Windows Phone project the `Load` method is firied not at the first time, only at second. So I have to go to `QuestionView` - nothing, go back and enter again and now everything is working. `Load` method is fired.
What is the problem?

Best,
Tomasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found usefull:
`ViewModelLocator`

```
#if NETFX_CORE //WINDOWS 8
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<QuestionViewModel>();
#else //WINDOWS_PHONE
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<QuestionViewModel>(true);
#endif
```

and registering services in `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```
 public App()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IQuestionService, QuestionService>();
    }
```

This solution is pretty nice no code-behind in Views and all functionalities of ViewModels are stored in `PCL` project.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewModel` behind `QuestionView` is probably not instantiated yet and can therefore not receive messages. Only after going to `QuestionView` the `ViewModel` gets instantiated (by the `ViewModelLocator`). If you want to send messages to the `QuestionViewModel` you should instantiate it immediately in the `ViewModelLocator` like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<QuestionViewModel>(true);
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: After this I get TargetInvocationException about one of my services `IQuestionService` which is called in `QuestionViewModel` I can not register this service in `ViewModelLocator` as Google said beacuse it is in PCL, so where I should register such services?